# Using 32bit Java library with JavaFX 2 (OS X)

Tags: java, javafx, compatibility, nxt, bluecove

I have written a small class using a 32bit Java library (http://bluecove.org/) to control a Lego Mindstorms NXT robot over Bluetooth. However, I would like to use this class now within a Java FX 2.0 application and Java FX 2.0 requires at least Java 7. The truth problem is that there is no Java 7 32bit JDK for OS X, so I can either run Java FX with Java 7 or the 32bit library with Java 6 but not both together.

My idea was now to write a small web service from where I have access to the 32bit library, however this is not very straight forward and for this reason I would like to ask if somebody has a better idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's no other possibility that having 2 VMs like you describe one running java6 32bit as the server and the 2nd running java7 client, to create the UI.